# Can login page can be tested in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Can login page (where we need to enter the credentials) be tested?
And URL of that website after login page can be tested without login?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter is able to simulate login event and represent authenticated user. See i.e. [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide for example configuration and associated correlations.

If you need to simulate N authenticated users and X unauthenticated ones you could use [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) for scenario distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is Yes and To a Large extent Yes.

Yes, Because it can be done for Web Page Logins and as Dmitiri said ASP.Net logins also.

Why i am Saying "to a Large Extent" is NTLM and Kerberos Authentication for Logins can be a bit troublesome. Where you need to be sure about the Domain names, the exact details.

Now, it depends where you are being asked for the User's Credentials . Normally for a Simple Web Page login - You Would get the URL from the address bar and you need to pass that.
For NTLM and Kerberos ones, you need to do some research so as to where you are getting authenticated and grab hold of that page.

We did for NTLM one and the login and authentication pages were different.